# Can't extract simple JSON to case class with json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I'm trying to use `json4s` in a worksheet to try it out, I want simply to extract a json to some case class:

```
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Extraction, JValue}

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val json = """{"name":"joe","age":15}"""

JsonMethods.parse(json).extract[Person]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the `implicit val jsonDefaultFormats = DefaultFormats` right after your `import`s.